# Have loaded a php variable into flash but cant apply it in a function

Tags: php, flash, actionscript, function, variables

hi I have created an actionscript function which stops an animation on a specific frame which works fine. I have then loaded in a php file with a variable which will contain the number for the frame i want the animation to stop on. This has loaded in fine and i have loaded it in a function. what i cant seem to do is to get the variable into the function which tells the animation to stop playing.

here is my code:

```
//load variables
varReceiver = new LoadVars(); // create an object to store the variables
varReceiver.load("http://playground.nsdesign6.net/percentage/external.php");
//load variables



//function1
varReceiver.onLoad = function() {
//value is the var that is created. 
var paul = this.percentage;
}
//function1


//function2
this.onEnterFrame = function() {    
if(this._currentframe==(percentage)) {
this.stop();
this.onEnterFrame = undefined;
}
}
play();
//function2
```

cheers
paul

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `percentage` is not defined within the scope of function2.

Try something like this:

```
//function1
varReceiver.onLoad = function() {
//value is the var that is created. 
var _level0.paul = this.percentage;
}
//function1

//function2
this.onEnterFrame = function() {    
if(this._currentframe==paul) {
this.stop();
this.onEnterFrame = undefined;
}
}
```

---

Another thing to be aware of is that you've already been through a couple of frames by the time your onLoad function is called, so maybe you should change your test in function2 to be `if(this._currentframe>=paul)` just in case paul is a small number.

Comment: hi i tried what you said but it doesnt work and comes up with the following errors: 

Scene=Scene 1, Layer=Layer 1, Frame=1: Line 12: ';' expected var _level0.paul = this.percentage; Scene=Scene 1, Layer=Layer 1, Frame=1: Line 14: Unexpected '}' encountered }

Answer (score 0):

```
//load variables
var paul; // <- !!!
varReceiver = new LoadVars(); // create an object to store the variables

varReceiver.onLoad = function() {
//value is the var that is created. 
   paul = this.percentage; // <- !!!
   play();
}
//function1


//function2
this.onEnterFrame = function() {    
   if(this._currentframe==(paul)) { // <- !!!
      this.stop();
      this.onEnterFrame = undefined;
   }
}
//function2

varReceiver.load("http://playground.nsdesign6.net/percentage/external.php");
```

or better:

```
//load variables
varReceiver = new LoadVars(); // create an object to store the variables

varReceiver.onLoad = function() { // onLoad
   if(this.percentage!=undefined){ // check if percentage exist
      _root.onEnterFrame = function(){ // register event function
         if(_currentframe == varRecivier.precentage) { // function body
            _root.stop();
            _root.onEnterFrame = null;
         }
      play();
   }else{ // no variable "precentage" in loaded data
      gotoAndPlay("error"); // loading error handling
   }
}
```